Slow std::fstream performance
I'm trying to process a bunch of HTML files (several thousand, each with a size of around 500KB) with a C++ executable, but I'm experiencing very poor performance when reading the files sequentially. The core C++ code is basically this:
int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> filePaths{ "file1", "file2", ... }; // Many file paths
  int i = 0;
  for (const std::string& filePath : filePaths) {
    std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
    std::cout << i++ << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}

I compiled this with MSVC 2022 as well as MinGW (GCC 13.1.0), both with standard CMake Release optimizations on. However the runtime performance on my quite modern machine (Win11, 32GB RAM, Ryzen 9, SSD) is far beneath of what I would have expected:

Extracting the std::ifstream file object out of the loop and using file.open/file.close in the loop or even using C-style fopen/fclose instead of std::ifstream makes no difference.
Am I missing something? I can't believe that it takes several minutes to just open (not even process yet) a few thousand small files...
Edit:
I ran the same binary on another Windows machine (also with Win11 and SSD) and got the same slow results.
Compiling and running the same code on a Mac Mini however gave the expected results: it finished within a few milliseconds.

Output to the console is slow. Try doing the loop without that. Though with your current code, the compiler might just decide to skip the loop entirely if there's nothing really happening inside it.

but I'm experiencing very poor performance when reading the files sequentially. -- Those files in that tight loop are opened and closed on each iteration.  Add to that the speed of outputting using std::cout.  Instead of cout, try to get a good utility program that shows the files being created and closed and monitor the speed of that (a lot of them require a "refresh" to see the new files, but that's another issue).

Omitting the output does not make it (significantly) faster, I'm afraid. As for the opening and closing one file on each iteration: Sure, that's intended, but how else would I process that many files in a reasonable amount of time?

do you need to read them sequentially ? opening the file itself is going to be slow, so i expect multithreading to give you a good boost in performance here, also check if an antivirus is interfering.

I do not even create files, but only read existing files.

check for antivirus interfering, add the executable path to the exclusion list, same for windows defender.

I've not yet tried multithreading, I wanted the check SO suggestions first because I still feel that I'm doing something basically wrong here

Checked antivirus and explicitly added my executable to the exclusion list, but still no difference.

Are you targeting your local filesystem or a remote on server?  Saw a Q like this a few months ago and the OP was using a network drive that was limited.

It's on the same local SSD.

It would be useful to see more of a [mcve]. There's no file reading in the example given, just opening and closing.

Yes, and just opening and closing already is as slow as experienced, without even reading/processing the files.

@csk On my machine using Visual Studio 2022 I created 5000 files in a single directory, 128k each. Using your loop, without the cout,  it takes ~90ms to complete. If I read all of the data from the files as well it takes ~540ms. If I add std::cout << i++ << "\n"; to the loop it takes ~2175ms. If you feel like filling in any missing details that might affect the timing please do, otherwise I feel like it is something to do with your particular situation.

"I ran the same binary on another Windows machine (also with Win11 and SSD) and got the same slow results." might be interesting if we could generate and run the same binary on different machines.

I think I finally found the reason: it was indeed Windows Defender (on both Windows machines) that slowed down the processing. As I already mentioned in a comment yesterday, I have added my executable to the Defender exclusion list, but that didn't change anything. However, I had to add the files directory to the exclusion list. The files were mostly HTML files, so I guess Defender did an extra check there when opening them?
This leaves room for another question: What steps would be necessary to make sure that someone else who uses the executable on their system to process HTML files wouldn't need to disable Antivirus software? Could signing the executable help?

I have rewritten your thing a bit, to show some numbers. Which, unfortunately, does little for your problem, but it just doesn't fit into a comment.
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <filesystem>
#include <vector>

static const std::string dir("/usr/include/");
// static const std::string dir("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2022\\Community");

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::string> filePaths;

    // find me a reasonably large number of files
    {
        boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer timer;
        for (auto const& entry : std::filesystem::recursive_directory_iterator(dir))
        {
            if (entry.is_regular_file())
            {
                filePaths.push_back(entry.path().string());
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "got " << filePaths.size() << " paths\n";

    // ... and open/close all of them
    {
        boost::timer::auto_cpu_timer timer;
        for (const std::string& filePath : filePaths)
        {
            std::ifstream file(filePath, std::ios::binary);
            if (!file.good())
            {
                std::cerr << "problem\n";
                return 1;
            }
#if 0
            // Ensure that the file IS open, in case the library
            // doesn't actually open the file until first access.
            // No idea whether it's actually permissible to do that.
            std::string test;
            file >> test;
#endif
            // std::cout << filePath << "\n";
        }
    }
    std::cout << "opened " << filePaths.size() << " paths\n";

    return 0;
}

stieber@gatekeeper:~ $ g++ Test.cpp -lboost_timer && ./a.out
 0.161745s wall, 0.080000s user + 0.080000s system = 0.160000s CPU (98.9%)
got 19386 paths
 0.349939s wall, 0.100000s user + 0.240000s system = 0.340000s CPU (97.2%)
opened 19386 paths

You're mostly interested in the second chunk, but I was too lazy to create 1000 files so I just took them from the system. Still, as you can see, neither chunk takes any significant amount of time, so your problem is either a very bad filesystem, or the console output.
So, let's just uncomment the output and try again:
...
/usr/include/iproute2/bpf_elf.h
/usr/include/fmtmsg.h
/usr/include/getopt.h
 0.652310s wall, 0.220000s user + 0.440000s system = 0.660000s CPU (101.2%)
opened 19386 paths

So even that doesn't change much for me...
Now, I've run some tests on Windows as well, using "Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition 17.10.0 Preview 2.0". I'm not too happy with the results because it's hard to reproduce, although I'm not THAT surprised.
The results above are from my Raspi, which runs off an SD card. My Windows box runs off an HDD -- and it's low on RAM since one of the modules died, and I'm inclined to replace a lot of the box so I'm accepting the swapping now, but that makes measurements difficult. Note that I get twice as many files, though.
Running it for the first time, unsurprisingly, gives rather bad results:
C:\Users\Christian\Source\Repos\SpeedTest\x64\Debug>.\SpeedTest.exe
 65.084869s wall, 0.406250s user + 1.000000s system = 1.406250s CPU (2.2%)
got 40259 paths
 807.232689s wall, 1.156250s user + 6.468750s system = 7.625000s CPU (0.9%)
opened 40259 paths

Obviously, horrible results. I'm inclined to assume that's mostly the HDD, so let me run it again to get some cache hits:
C:\Users\Christian\Source\Repos\SpeedTest\x64\Debug>.\SpeedTest.exe
 0.770629s wall, 0.359375s user + 0.406250s system = 0.765625s CPU (99.4%)
got 40259 paths
 122.991317s wall, 0.812500s user + 3.078125s system = 3.890625s CPU (3.2%)
opened 40259 paths

Better, but not great. Still... another attempt?
C:\Users\Christian\Source\Repos\SpeedTest\x64\Debug>.\SpeedTest.exe
 0.673051s wall, 0.234375s user + 0.437500s system = 0.671875s CPU (99.8%)
got 40259 paths
 2.038030s wall, 0.234375s user + 1.750000s system = 1.984375s CPU (97.4%)
opened 40259 paths

Now we're talking. Maybe something interfered on the second run, and the third run got everything from the cache; I can't tell.
Can I get a better result? Trying it a fourth time increased the walltime to almost 4 seconds, so... still, much better than the second run.
Its still considerably slower than my Raspi version (twice as many files but more than 5 times the runtime) but I'll stop here for now since it's not such a major problem for me :-)
@csk, did you run your test multiple times?

So at least I'm not doing anything basically wrong (disabling the console output didn't make it faster - actually, I added the console output for inspection because it was so slow)
I will try my code on a different machine and report back.

I also did an additional test, with actually doing a read on the file -- this was mostly to ensure the library wasn't optimizing the "open" away until the first access to the file actually happens. It did make things slightly slower -- the version without output said "0.501821s wall, 0.160000s user + 0.320000s system = 0.480000s CPU (95.7%)", but half a second for 20000 files still isn't too bad.

Of course the filesystem is different, but I've never heard about NTFS being particularly  problematic. It might be, but then again, it would just prove that the problem is not with the ifstream as such, but either NTFS or the library on whatever compiler is being used. If the design of the fstream stuff was inherently problematic, it would show on all platforms... well, I am going to try it on VisualStudio to see what happens, although without the measurements.

It takes me about 17s to open and read an int from 100,000 files on my Windows machine (Ryzen 9 5900x, Samsung 980 Pro SSD), so OP's results still seem pretty far out of step with what I would expect on Windows.

@ChristianStieber I did multiple runs, however always with the same results, regardless if it was compiled with MSVC 2022 or MinGW (GCC 13.1.0). The same binary and files on a different Windows machine (also with a SSD) gave the same extremely slow results (obviously far from everything you measured on your systems).
However, compiling and running the same code on macOS (with Clang) was extremely fast, as it should be.
